# Jquery DropDownlist undefined item IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, undefined

```
$.get("CallBack.aspx", { nm: StateTx, nm2: StateTx2 }, function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function() {
                        $('[id$=DropDown1]').append("<option value=" + this['I3D'] + ">" + this['prmv'] + "</option>");
                    });
                });
```

my problem ie8 last item undefined. how do fix ?

```
Amain cm2 = new Amain();
DataTable dt = cm2.Getdt(str, str3);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("[");
foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
    sb.Append("{");
    sb.Append("\"prmv\":\"");
    sb.Append(item[0].ToString());
    sb.Append("\"" + "},");
}

sb.Append("]");

Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
Context.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen because of the way IE handles Javascript arrays. In IE,

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4,];
```

has five elements, the last of which is undefined. In Firefox, the last comma is ignored so the list has four elements.

Have a look at the exact data your `Callback.aspx` is returning.

**Update**: Your callback code causes this problem on the line:

```
                sb.Append("\"" + "},");
```

This will produce an array like:

```
[{"prmv":"1"},{"prmv":"2"},{"prmv":"3"},{"prmv":"4"},]
                                                    ^ extra comma
```

There is an extra comma before the `]` of the returned array. One way to fix this might be to:

```
sb.Remove(sb.Length-1, 1); // remove extra trailing comma
sb.Append("]");
```

This fix will work for both IE and Firefox (and all other browsers).

Comment: @oraclee: Yes, but perhaps your `Callback.aspx` is formatting data in such as way as to include a trailing comma in the array. Perhaps you could post the code for `Callback.aspx` if it's not too long.